# Fancybox working on some links but not others

Tags: php, wordpress, fancybox

I am currently having a few problems with fancybox. If you take a look at the link below you will see I have got it working on the portfolio boxes but not in the menubar at the top which is generated by the wp_list_pages command. I have tried appending "fancybox" a class using jquery and also targeting the elements themselves when running the fancybox script but nothing seems to work.

http://www.astwood.co.uk/testsite/wordpress/

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I cracked it, I had to add

```
data-fancybox-type="iframe"
```

to every link which I did with wp_list_pages by adding this onto the functions file:

```
add_filter('wp_list_pages', create_function('$t', 'return str_replace("<a ", "<a data-fancybox-type=\"iframe\" ", $t);'));
```